# TeamCity build agent ignores gradle productFlavors for Android

Tags: android, gradle, teamcity

I have four productFlavors in my Android project:

```
productFlavors {
    blue {}
    red {}
    top {}
    bottom {}
}
```

Also I have `string.xml` for each flavor and for two combinations: `blueTop` and `redTop`. Each `string.xml` contains its own `app_name`.

So when I make apk in Android Studio using code like `gradlew assembleBlueTopRelease` the app names are correct, but when I run the TeamCity agent, it ignores all the other `string.xml`s and set names for all apks to default, specified in `main/res/values/strings.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault! The folders name were `bluetop` and `redtop` (instead of `blueTop` and `redTop`). When I build it with Android Studio on Windows it was ok, but building with Linux agent is the problem)